# Header issue, wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, header

Tried to make a change to the address in the header.php, and for some reason it changed only in the index file and not in any of the other pages.  Can anyone tell me why this is?

In the index page and both other page template options the header is called the same...

```
<?php
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />

<title>Bernice's Bakery</title>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<?php
    if ( is_singular() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) )
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    wp_head();
?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="wrapper" class="hfeed">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="bbheader">
            <h1><a href="http://www.bernicesbakerymt.com">bernice's</a></h1>
            <h1 style="padding-top:31px;"><a href="http://www.bernicesbakerymt.com">bakery</a></h1>
            <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
            <p>190 S. 3rd W. Missoula, MT 59801 728-1358</p>
        </div>
        <div id="masthead">
            <div id="branding" role="banner">
                <?php $heading_tag = ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) ? 'h1' : 'div'; ?>

            </div><!-- #branding -->

            <div id="access" role="navigation">
              <?php /*  Allow screen readers / text browsers to skip the navigation menu and get right to the good stuff */ ?>
                <div class="skip-link screen-reader-text"><a href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to content', 'twentyten' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'twentyten' ); ?></a></div>
                <?php /* Our navigation menu.  If one isn't filled out, wp_nav_menu falls back to wp_page_menu.  The menu assiged to the primary position is the one used.  If none is assigned, the menu with the lowest ID is used.  */ ?>
                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
            </div><!-- #access -->
        </div><!-- #masthead -->
    </div><!-- #header -->

    <div id="main">
```

The address is correct in this code.  On the rest of the pages it says "109 S. 3rd..."

Site: http://www.bernicesbakerymt.com/

Comment: You don't have a `/wp-content/cache` folder or anything, do you? Some sort of server-side cache sounds likely in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do a find-replace operation in your theme's root folder.  Look for the text "109 S." and you'll probably find another file that has the wrong address.

Comment: Unfortunatley, not the answer - the only place it existed was in the header.php...

Comment: Oops, that WAS the answer.  Found an extra instance of header.php in another folder.  Thanks @Stephen

Comment: No problem.  Glad you found it.